# How to Tidying Up / Justify my Table in Tikz

Tags: tables

I want to make this table of mine tidy, the placement of the probability at second rows are a mess, and the first rows has too many gap too.

This is the table code:

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{array}  
\begin{document}
    \centering
\begin{table}[htbp] \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}  
    \[      
    \begin{array}{c|cccc} 
        \hline x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\              
        \hline P(X=x) & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{8} 
    \end{array}  
    \]     
    \caption{The probability distribution of $X$, a listing of all possible values of $X$, together with their corresponding probabilities.}
\end{table}  

\end{document}
```

thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but from your code chunk is not possible to figure out, how your table should look. See, if the following MWE gives what you after: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{array} 
\begin{document}\centering\begin{table} \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} 
\[     
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\hline x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\             
\hline P(X=x)   & \frac{1}{8}                 
      & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{8}
\end{array} 
\]    
\end{table} 
\end{document}`. If not, please provide a sketch of desired table.

Comment: Where is the Ti*k*Z part in this table?

Comment: When you copy your snippet into a fresh file, it won‘t compile. It can‘t. Please make it a habit to present only code, which compiles. As an aside that also avoids certain questions.

Comment: @Zarko yes it is what I after..

Comment: @JasperHabicht maybe it is not TikZ, I am at the wrong room then. Sorry.

Comment: @MS-SPO  I am writing a long pages and this table is only a small portion, I would not possibly copy all the writing here. It is a table inside a very long writing of mine. Like writing a Calculus book.

Comment: The length is not the point. Try copying into a new .tex file and compile. Then hopefully you'll understand. We are interested in the necessary parts of your code, which shows the problem, not in a copy of your long one. So, please complete and prune your code as needed.

Comment: @FreyatheGoddess, I extend my comment to answer ...

Comment: I edit my first post and the code already nice to me now @MS-SPO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table code if full of clutter of `\multicolumn`s and `\mulotirows` Both are superfluous ...

Two possible solutions:

- with `array` table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\[  \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\hline x        & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline P(X=x)   & \frac{1}{8}
                    & \frac{3}{8}
                        & \frac{3}{8}
                            & \frac{1}{8}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

- with `tblr` of `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = { Q[c,$] | *{4}{Q[c, $]} }}
    \hline
x         &  0  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \hline
P(X=x)    &  \frac{1}{8}
                & \frac{3}{8}
                    & \frac{3}{8}
                        & \frac{1}{8}
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Both gives the same result:

[image]

Comment: You know I follow tutorial online thus that's why I use `multicolumn` I don't even know this method is more efficient. I add `[htbp]` also to make the table appear after the text that I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to interpret and provide solutions to your question. I read it this way:

- make code appear cleaner and easier to grasp
- make the print-out more pleasant to read.

Here are a few strategies to achieve this.

### 1. Making code appear cleaner

The secret is to use white space to your advantage, just like layouters do. Indenting is part of this strategy. Perhaps you know it from structured programming. However, I'd like to call it `defensive programming`, making structural hickups almost self-evident. So after a first rearrangement your code may look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}%     it's easier to grasp this way on the fly  


\begin{document}
  % ~~~ indenting, in the tradition of strucutred programming ~~
  \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering%     you probably only want the table centered
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    % ~~~ reflect intended structure in code itself ~
    \[      
    \begin{array}{c|cccc} 
        \hline
         x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\              
        \hline
        P(X=x) & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{8} 
               & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{8} 
    \end{array}  
    \]     
    \caption{The probability distribution of $X$, a listing of all possible values of $X$, together with their corresponding probabilities.}
  \end{table} 
  
\end{document}
```

[image: result-1]

What is a bit distracting in my view: the long caption. So let's source it out into a macro `\cptn`, which will clean-up the lower table code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}%     it's easier to grasp this way on the fly  

% ~~~ some shorthand; hatch the needed % (!) inside macros ~~~
\newcommand\cptn[0]{The probability distribution of $X$, a%
                    listing of all possible values of $X$,%
                    together with their corresponding% 
                    probabilities.}
                    
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
  % ~~~ indenting, in the tradition of strucutred programming ~~
  \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering%     you probably only want the table centered
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    % ~~~ reflect intended structure in code itself ~
    \[      
    \begin{array}{c|cccc} 
        \hline
         x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\              
        \hline
        P(X=x) & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{8} 
               & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{8} 
    \end{array}  
    \]     
    \caption{\cptn}
  \end{table} 
  
\end{document}
```

[image: result-2]

### 2. Let's do typesetting for tables in books

It's good practice amongst layouters of books to remove almost all table lines, backgrounds and shadings. Package `booktabs` is made for this.

So we need to arrive at a table, which I can't at the moment because you use package `array`. So, let's transform it into a table-structure.

Here's the result, with some work left to do, after some "code-pottery":

- replaced `array` by `tabular`
- introduced macro `\mathline` to have one line in math-modes
- abbreviated the duplicate `\frac`-terms.

The result will be better in a moment.

```
\documentclass{article}

% ~~~ some shorthand; watch the needed % (!) inside macros ~~~
\newcommand\cptn[0]{The probability distribution of $X$, a%
                    listing of all possible values of $X$,%
                    together with their corresponding% 
                    probabilities.}

% ~~~ one table line in math-mode ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\mathline[5]{$#1$ & $#2$ & $#3$ & $#4$ & $#5$}

% ~~~ let's abbreviate those repeating fractions ~~~~~~~
\newcommand\fr[0]{\frac{1}{8}}
\newcommand\frk[0]{\frac{3}{8}}
                    
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
  % ~~~ indenting, in the tradition of strucutred programming ~~
  \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering%     you probably only want the table centered

    % ~~~ reflect intended structure in code itself ~
    \begin{tabular}{c|cccc} 
        \hline          
        \mathline{x}{0}{1}{2}{3} \\              
        \hline
        \mathline{P(X=x)}{\fr}{\frk}{\frk}{\fr}
    \end{tabular}  
    \caption{\cptn}
  \end{table} 
  
\end{document}
```

[image: result-3]

So finally let's make the move towards `booktabs`. This package provides:

- `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` with slightly thicker lines at both ends of a table
- `\midrule` for any horizontal rules inside the table (use like a rare spice)
- in addition this package introduces some "air" (white space) to make a table look nicer in a book.

Following the layout idea of having no vertical rules the column specifier became simply `{ccccc}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% ~~~ some shorthand; watch the needed % (!) inside macros ~~~
\newcommand\cptn[0]{The probability distribution of $X$, a%
                    listing of all possible values of $X$,%
                    together with their corresponding% 
                    probabilities.}

% ~~~ one table line in math-mode ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\mathline[5]{$#1$ & $#2$ & $#3$ & $#4$ & $#5$}

% ~~~ let's abbreviate those repeating fractions ~~~~~~~
\newcommand\fr[0]{\frac{1}{8}}
\newcommand\frk[0]{\frac{3}{8}}
                    
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
  % ~~~ indenting, in the tradition of strucutred programming ~~
  \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering%     you probably only want the table centered

    % ~~~ reflect intended structure in code itself ~
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc} 
        \toprule         
        \mathline{x}{0}{1}{2}{3} \\              
        \midrule
        \mathline{P(X=x)}{\fr}{\frk}{\frk}{\fr}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}  
    \caption{\cptn}
  \end{table} 
  
\end{document}
```

And there you are:

[image: result-4]